# Remove Left arrow from SupportActionbar but keep logo

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am able to do this but I now can not click the logo.  It doesn't fire onOptionsItemSelected()..

```
actionBar= getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setTitle("");
        actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

if i set actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  the arrow shows up.  I have found a clone of this question, on SO but no one answered it correctly.  Someone suggested using a transparent image for teh arrow but how do I override that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, use

> setHomeAsUpIndicator()

Like this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.logo);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Yes you are correct with a minor tweak.
  actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
  actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
  actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo_padding));

i had to create a new drawable to give padding to the left otherwise it would be flush against the left side of the screen with 0 padding.